# Kalman.cs class not available in emgucv 3.x version?

Tags: emgucv

How can i implement kalman filter in emgu cv 3.x versions as explained in emgu wiki official code example. The particular class kalman.cs is not available in higher versions than 2.4. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you are having trouble. In the 3.3 version if you look in the documentation, the Kalman filter class is described in the Emgu.CV section. You can [See this](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.3.0/document/html/ebe1097b-0948-e8e1-5aeb-f7d55bfebc5c.htm). If you are trying to get the Kalman filter example program running, that was done for an earlier version and you will have to do the work to get it to run I am afraid. Maybe someone has done that already. If so, update the question.

Doug

Answer (score 0):

class "kalman.cs" in version 2.4 is changed to "KalmanFilter.cs" in version 3.3. They also changed class Matrix in 2.4 to Mat in 3.3
you can see in this link [link].
(http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.3.0/document/html/ebe1097b-0948-e8e1-5aeb-f7d55bfebc5c.htm )!

Emgu.CV.KalmanFilter